# Owl Carousel inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, foreach, owl-carousel

I am using Laravel Vue JS. I am displaying dynamically sections on homepage and i want to show image slider inside each sections

I have one foreach loop for all the sections and inside that loop i want to show slider of another image loop

FOR EXAMPLE :

```
<?php foreach() { ?>
<div class="owl-carousel 3-column-slider-carosal">

    <?php foreach() { ?>
    <div>
        <img src="image path">
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

And Below is my code

```
<template v-for="(home, index) in homepageData">

        <template v-if="home.section_type === 1">
            
            <section class="py-40 my-40" :style="`background-color: ${home.color_code}`">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 offset-lg-3 offset-md-3">
                        <div class="final-heading">
                            <h1 class="text-center text-capitalize" >Title<span>Description</span></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="bg-sec-white">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="owl-carousel 3-column-slider-carosal">
                            <div class="trend-block">
                                <div class="trend-img overflow-hidden mb-2">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('1.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid w-100">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="trend-block">
                                <div class="trend-img overflow-hidden mb-2">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('2.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid w-100">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="trend-block">
                                <div class="trend-img overflow-hidden mb-2">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('3.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid w-100">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="trend-block">
                                <div class="trend-img overflow-hidden mb-2">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('4.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid w-100">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="trend-block">
                                <div class="trend-img overflow-hidden mb-2">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('5.jpg') }}" class="img-fluid w-100">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
            
        </template>

    </template>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you attempted to run the code already? If so, can you provide some more information in your question, such as any error messages or logging output?

Comment: What are the foreach() expressions?